# How can I create new columns with developmental stage duration based on previous columns in r?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that represents animal development over time. I have columns with treatments and species then many columns representing days. It looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame (Species  = c("sp1", "sp1", "sp2"),
                  Treatment = c("hot", "cold", "hot"),
                  Apr1 = c("egg", "egg", "egg"),
                  Apr2 = c("1", "egg", "1"),
                  Apr3 = c("2", "egg", "1"),
                  Apr4 = c("adult", "1", "2"))
```

I need to create columns that tell me the number of days in each stage and the total development time so that I can compare these values across species and treatments.
I want the data frame to look like this output:

```
  Species Treatment Apr1 Apr2 Apr3  Apr4 Egg Instar1 Instar2 DaysToAdult
1     sp1       hot  egg    1    2 adult   1       1       1           4
2     sp1      cold  egg  egg  egg     1   3       1       0          NA
3     sp2       hot  egg    1    1     2   1       2       1          NA
```

Is there a function that pulls that values from previous columns fairly easily? I have ~15 developmental stages, so it would be possible to create each column individually if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played around with it for a while and finally got there:

```
df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(
         Egg = rowSums(df == "egg"),
         Instar1 = rowSums(df == "1"),
         Instar2 = rowSums(df == "2"),
         DaysToAdults = Egg + Instar1 + Instar2
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the intended analyses may be much easier to perform if we convert the data.frame to the `long` format beforehand:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df |>
    mutate(index = row_number(),
           .before = everything()) |> 
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Apr"),
                 names_to = "Apr",
                 names_transform = \(x) str_extract(x, "\\d")) |> 
    type_convert()|> 
    group_by(index) |>
    reframe(days_to_adult = min(Apr[value == "adult"]) |> 
                {\(x) ifelse(is.infinite(x), NA, x)}())

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  index days_to_adult
  <int>         <dbl>
1     1             4
2     2            NA
3     3            NA
```